# facebook developer posting to facebook but not showing on page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post an image to a facebook page from a PHP script on my server.  Everything is authenticating my account with admin rights and I have the permissions of manage_pages, publish_pages and publish_actions.

The image is getting uploaded and I can go to my facebook page and click on Notifications and the post is there, but when I go to Page, Posts, or Images I don't see it.  Also, when I look at it in the notification section it is showing it posted by me and as a visitor, it should be showing as posted by the Page. I do have this set as live in Facebook Developer as well.

Can anyone help?

When I run the script I am doing this call to facebook:

```
      $response = $fb->post('/'.$agency_permissions['facebook_page'].'/photos', $data, $agency_permissions['facebook_token']);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Facebook returns this information: (things labeled '{removed by me}' were removed by me, not returned that way)

```
Facebook\FacebookResponse Object(

[httpStatusCode:protected] => 200
[headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => *
        [Pragma] => no-cache
        [Cache-Control] => private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
        [facebook-api-version] => v2.11
        [Expires] => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
        [x-fb-rev] => 3698059
        [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
        [x-fb-trace-id] => H3yiZBKJGQe
        [Strict-Transport-Security] => max-age=15552000; preload
        [Vary] => Accept-Encoding
        [X-FB-Debug] => {removed by me}
        [Date] => Tue, 06 Mar 2018 20:43:16 GMT
        [Connection] => keep-alive
        [Content-Length] => 70
    )

[body:protected] => {"id":"1139098132893012","post_id":"335620470144697_1139098132893012"}
[decodedBody:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1139098132893012
        [post_id] => 335620470144697_1139098132893012
    )

[request:protected] => Facebook\FacebookRequest Object
    (
        [app:protected] => Facebook\FacebookApp Object
            (
                [id:protected] => {removed by me}
                [secret:protected] => {removed by me}
            )

        [accessToken:protected] => {removed by me}
        [method:protected] => POST
        [endpoint:protected] => /335620470144697/photos
        [headers:protected] => Array
            (
                [Content-Type] => multipart/form-data; boundary=5a9efd619ebd5
            )

        [params:protected] => Array
            (
                [message] => test
            )

        [files:protected] => Array
            (
                [source] => Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile Object
                    (
                        [path:protected] => /home/virtual/my_domain/public_html/wp-content///DemoUnitsInternal/7801.jpg
                        [maxLength:Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile:private] => -1
                        [offset:Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile:private] => -1
                        [stream:protected] => Resource id #26
                    )

            )

        [eTag:protected] => 
        [graphVersion:protected] => v2.11
    )

[thrownException:protected] => 
)
```

Comment: why publish_actions? you do not need this permission. and the problem itself is very well known, there are many threads about it on stackoverflow already. just use a page token instead of a user token.

Comment: I did try it without publish_actions using a page token and when I go to publish it tells me I need the page_actions permission.  I don't know if I need to change something else to have it override that.  The fact that it is showing me posting as myself as a visitor makes me wonder if there is something else I am missing and maybe that is why it tells me I need publish_actions?

Comment: you only need publish_actions for posting as user. to post "as page", you need manage_pages and publish_pages, and you have to use a page token. you are definitely not using a page token, but a user token.

Comment: Change to my last response...just removed the publish_actions and reset all the cookies, and went back in and did a publish to the image.  It looks like it went through but it still isn't showing on the site anywhere other than the Notifcations

Comment: I thought I had a page token...let me go through all the code and review it...I'll post here after I do that.

Comment: I figured out what happened...I had the page token and wrote it to my cookie but then I was calling the facebook token instead...everything is good now....thanks for helping me realize what was wrong with it :)

Comment: you are welcome. i turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a User Token, that´s why it gets posted as user. Make sure to use a Page Token with `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` and it will be posted as Page.